# When reading (consuming) a Kafka topics can you determine the schema version/id used when the message was produced

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I have a a C# consumer of a Kafka topic but I would like to know the version/id of the message that is being read.  Is this attribute available somehow in the ComsumeResult? or is there some other way to know what the version was of the produced record.  The reason I ask is that the Producer keeps changing the version and I what like to track from the consumed message the version it was produced with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Kafka doesn't have schemas, by default. I assume you are using Confluent Schema Registry?

That being said, after deserialization, no.

You would need to consume the data as bytes, then observe bytes 1-4 as an integer

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format

Comment: Yes -- exactly -- just to be complete you'll need the following:                                               
 if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
  Array.Reverse(bytes);
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

Comment: I'm not sure you need to check endianness, but looks right, assuming you skip the first byte `ToInt32(bytes, 1)`